# Center menu inside div

Tags: html, css

I cant center horizontally my menu inside my div. It is already centered vertically, but how can I center horizontally too with CSS? Thanks for any advice.

Code:

```
<div class="container-2">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="navbar-header nav menu-nav">
                    <li><a href="1.html">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="2.html">2</a></li>
                    <li>logo</li>
                    <li><a href="3.html">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="4.html">4</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
display: inline-block;
margin: auto auto;
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;}


.container-2{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.755);
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;   
}


.menu-nav{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle from jsfiddle.net

Comment: I believe you reversed "horizontal" and "vertical". Your question seems to be focused on the other way around. Also, this question can be solved with a simple google search.

Comment: if you reset display to table, then margin:auto is to be used on .menu. drop absolute position

Comment: Changing `.container-2`'s atribute `height: auto;` to `height: 100%;` will probably get you the result you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow the `display:table` methode , you have to clean up your CSS and use `display:table;` + `margin:auto` and **then** `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;` to make it work properly:  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/t5C8e/)**

```
.menu{
margin: auto auto;
display: table;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
}
.menu-nav{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.755);
    padding:0;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu-nav li{
display:inline-block;/* whatever you wanna do with your li */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your **CSS** code like this :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/km2Yu/1/embedded/result/) ([Source](http://jsfiddle.net/km2Yu/1/))

```
.menu{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto auto;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}


.container-2{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.755);
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}


.menu-nav{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

So you need to add `text-align: center;` to `.container-2` and remove `display: table-cell;` from `.menu`

---

## Update: With Vertical Center

you can simply try this :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/km2Yu/5/embedded/result/) ([Source](http://jsfiddle.net/km2Yu/5/))

```
.menu{
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}

.container-2{
    width: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.755);
    position: relative;
    height: auto;   
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
}
```

---

### Third Solution

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/km2Yu/8/embedded/result/) ([Source](http://jsfiddle.net/km2Yu/8/))

### HTML

```
<div class="container-2">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu_inside">
            <ul class="navbar-header nav menu-nav">
                <li><a href="1.html">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="2.html">2</a></li>
                <li>logo</li>
                <li><a href="3.html">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="4.html">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.menu{
    margin: auto auto;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu_inside{
    display: inline-block;
}

.container-2{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.755);
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
}

.menu-nav{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that if I remove display:table-cell from .menu it removes my vertical align, any other option? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @user3790637 I've updated my answer.. take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5V6gK/

CSS Code:

```
.menu {width:100%; text-align:center;}
.menu li {float:left; margin:0 10px;}
.menu ul {float:none; clear:both; width:auto; margin:0 auto; list-style-type:none; display:inline-block;}
```

You need to give a full-width to the `.menu` class.
The inner element (`<ul>`) should have `width:auto; display:inline-block; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;`.

The list items should be floated next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

This will make your content aligned in the middle position from both up & down and left & right. Replace this into your .menu class.

Or

If this doesn't work properly, Try:

```
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
```