# How do I center a navigation bar in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Baically - I am new to HTML/CSS and I want to center this navigation bar:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  background-color: rgb(4, 210, 129);
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: "Monospace", Lucida Console;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(109, 245, 208);
}

li img {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(4, 210, 129);
}

div {}

.current {
  background-color: rgb(109, 245, 208);
}

.end {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(4, 210, 129);
  padding: 23px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40%
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><img src="IMG/logo.png" class="logo" /></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <!-- <li class="end"></li> -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

What I would like to know, is why I can't control the nav bar by using the div element, or by assigning a class or id?

The only way I can control it is by using li a, li img etc.

Why is this? and is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492388/center-menu-inside-div

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're using `float: left` on your `li` items.
To quote from [mozilla web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float);

> The `float` CSS property specifies that an element should be placed along the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it. The element is removed from the normal flow of the web page, though still remaining a part of the flow [...]

Because it's escaped from the flow, doing `text-align: center` will not affect the `li` objects.

Instead of using `float: left`, try `display: inline-block` to achieve the desired effect, on both `li` and `a`. This leaves a space between the blocks (which is really just all the spaces in your file from indenting), but that can be fixed by setting `font-size: 0` in the containing element (`ul`); you'll just have to style the font size in the objects where there actually is text to the appropriate size. Once you do that you can apply `text-align: center` to the `ul` element to center the objects.

Here's a demonstration. To see the result, click the "run code snippet" button.
 (PS: As Facundo said, you don't need the `div` surrounding the `ul` element.)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  background-color: rgb(4, 210, 129);
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Monospace", Lucida Console;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(109, 245, 208);
}

li img {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(4, 210, 129);
}

div {}

.current {
  background-color: rgb(109, 245, 208);
}

.end {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(4, 210, 129);
  padding: 23px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Lorem</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="IMG/logo.png" class="logo" /></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <!-- <li class="end"></li> -->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<body>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, the reason I put the nav there was to assign it a class and try to style by class not by the tags. But it doesn't work all together, it has to be seperated and styled by tags. Why is this and how can I fix it? - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp code from here

Comment: This is for the same reason I previously mentioned; the `float` class moves the objects out of the flow of the document. You can basically move all the changes I added to the `ul` styling onto a class like `.navigation` and it'll have the same effect once you give the `ul` object the `navigation` class.

Comment: Does this mean I can have something like:

<nav class="navbar">
<lists in here>
</nav>

.navbar {
every bit of styling
} then not need to use any tags in the css?

Comment: You can do something like `.navbar {font-size: 0; text-align: center}` in the CSS, though you'll still need to keep the `li` formatting since those don't have classes attached to them (like `.navbar li {display: inline-block; font-size: 16px; [...other styling you have...]}`)

Comment: if i assign a class to every <li> and every href in the list it still wont let me use that to style it?

Comment: Have you removed `float: left` from your `li` styling?